# ExtentReport - TestNG IReporter ISuite Error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, extent

I am trying to add an ExtentReport - TestNG IReporter for my Automation Testing Suite.

Below is the complete code for Class **ExtentTestNGIReporterListener**

```
package com.util;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.testng.IReporter;
import org.testng.IResultMap;
import org.testng.ISuite;
import org.testng.ISuiteResult;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentHtmlReporter;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.ChartLocation;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.Theme;

public class ExtentTestNGIReporterListener implements IReporter {
    private static final String OUTPUT_FOLDER = "test-output/";
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "Extent.html";

    private ExtentReports extent;

    @Override
    public void generateReport(List xmlSuites, List suites, String outputDirectory) {
        init();

        for (ISuite suite : suites) {
            Map result = suite.getResults();

            for (ISuiteResult r : result.values()) {
                ITestContext context = r.getTestContext();

                buildTestNodes(context.getFailedTests(), Status.FAIL);
                buildTestNodes(context.getSkippedTests(), Status.SKIP);
                buildTestNodes(context.getPassedTests(), Status.PASS);

            }
        }

        for (String s : Reporter.getOutput()) {
            extent.setTestRunnerOutput(s);
        }

        extent.flush();
    }

    private void init() {
        ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(OUTPUT_FOLDER + FILE_NAME);
        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("ExtentReports - Created by TestNG Listener");
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName("ExtentReports - Created by TestNG Listener");
        htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.BOTTOM);
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);

        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
        extent.setReportUsesManualConfiguration(true);
    }

    private void buildTestNodes(IResultMap tests, Status status) {
        ExtentTest test;

        if (tests.size() > 0) {
            for (ITestResult result : tests.getAllResults()) {
                test = extent.createTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName());

                for (String group : result.getMethod().getGroups())
                    test.assignCategory(group);

                if (result.getThrowable() != null) {
                    test.log(status, result.getThrowable());
                } else {
                    test.log(status, "Test " + status.toString().toLowerCase() + "ed");
                }

                test.getModel().setStartTime(getTime(result.getStartMillis()));
                test.getModel().setEndTime(getTime(result.getEndMillis()));
            }
        }
    }

    private Date getTime(long millis) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(millis);
        return calendar.getTime();
    }
}
```

From the above code, I found an error for **ISuite** and **IsuiteResult** in for loop declaration

Compile time error is added as the comments at specific line.

```
@Override
    public void generateReport(List xmlSuites, List suites, String outputDirectory) {
        init();

        for (ISuite suite : suites) {  // Error - Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to ISuite
            Map result = suite.getResults();

            for (ISuiteResult r : result.values()) { // Error - Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to ISuiteResult

                ITestContext context = r.getTestContext();

                buildTestNodes(context.getFailedTests(), Status.FAIL);
                buildTestNodes(context.getSkippedTests(), Status.SKIP);
                buildTestNodes(context.getPassedTests(), Status.PASS);

            }
        }

        for (String s : Reporter.getOutput()) {
            extent.setTestRunnerOutput(s);
        }

        extent.flush();
    }
```

Please help to resolve the issue.

Source: [extentreports](http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#testng-ireporter)

Comment: generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites.... Add the types in method declaration

Comment: @Grasshopper - Above helped to resolve the error for iSuiteResult. But still stuck with the error for 
`for (ISuiteResult r : result.values())`

Comment: Try Map<String,ISuiteResult> result = suite.getResults(); in place of  Map result = suite.getResults();

Comment: @Grasshopper Thanks it helped!!